# SQL Pivot with duplicates and same two first columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Hello first time working with sql pivots . I have a table from a sql query like this below returning from the sql query.

```
Serial  | SerialV2 | MeterType | MeterAmount
A1      |  A11     |   gas     | 12
A1      |  A11     | odometer  | 1252
A2      |  A22     |   gas     | 10
A2      |  A22     | odometer  | 105
A1      |  A12     |   gas     | 1
A1      |  A12     | odometer  | 17542
```

I would like it to be this

```
Serial  | SerialV2 | gas | odometer
A1      |  A11     | 12  | 1252
A1      |  A12     | 1   | 17542
A2      |  A22     | 10  | 105
```

what I have so far written is

```
select serial, serialV2, [gas], [odometer]
from (
//sql query here 
) query
PIVOT 
(
sum(meterAmount)
FOR [meterType] in ([gas], [odometer])
) as p
order by serial
```

Will i have problem with the record that has the same serial number but not the V2 serial number?

Also, what would happen if a another dupllicate record showed up i.e. serial and serialV2 is the same?

Thanks!

Comment: gmoney your query is correct, it gives you your desired results.  The one thing I will note is in the from ( ) query... you actually can just do from tablename if it is one table to simplify it a little for you

Comment: The query inside is quite complex I created this example to simplify thank you for the heads up though! Do you know what would happen if I have a duplicate row i.e. (serial and serial v2 are the same as another row)

Comment: @gmoney It would sum the values.

Comment: shawnt00 is correct.  The pivot performs a group by which is pretty much the same as the conditional aggregation example sgeddes answered with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select serial, serialV2, 
    sum(case when metertype = 'gas' then meteramount end) as gas,
    sum(case when metertype = 'odometer' then meteramount end) as odometer
from (
   //sql query here 
) query
group by serial, serialV2
```